# JHipster building production profile

Tags: java, maven, heroku, jhipster

Running Windows 10 platform with the following stack:

- Java 1.8.0_92
- Maven 3.3.9
- JHipster 4.1.0
- Yarn 0.20.3

The application generated is a monolith with AngularJS. Using HTTP Auth - no social plugins.

I am current testing deployment to Heroku and ran into a problem where the deployment simply stops.
I have used the following command before with success to deploy more than one app to Heroku:

```
yo jhipster:heroku
```

This is preferred method to deploy to Heroku according to the documentation.

Since then I have added PostgreSQL and some entities plus a bit of other code. Running with SpringBoot and yarn locally works 100%.
I then tried to deploy to Heroku with the above command, but the process simply hangs.
I have tried different options, event upgaded JHipster from 4.0.8 to 4.1.0, regenerating the application from scratch, leaving out all my custom changes...nothing helps.

It seems as if the Maven packaging process is the guilty party here. I then tried to build locally with Maven and the dev profile - success. Changing to prod profile experiences the same process where it just hangs with no response. Both processes stop at the same output.

```
mvnw package -Pprod -DskipTests
```

> [INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:yarn (webpack build prod) @ test-postgre-sql ---
>
> [INFO] Running 'yarn run webpack:prod' in D:\DevelopmentProjects\JHipster\TestPostgreSQL
>
> [INFO] yarn run v0.21.3
>
> [INFO] $ yarn test && webpack -p --config webpack/webpack.vendor.js && webpack -p --config webpack/webpack.prod.js

That is the last output and the process simply hangs. The Windows resource / performance monitor shows no activity in the network, CPU, memory or disk areas that indicates any activity. Leaving it for 8 hours doesn't help either.

This indicates that the problem exists before the Heroku settings are getting involved.

Any ideas where to start looking for a solution.

Comment: I have now rebuild the complete environment  - deleted Yarn, NPM and Node with all their caches.
Restarted with Node and Yarn via Msi.

The laptop I'm running on is a MSI Gaming machine with 16Gig of Memory, SSD's for hard disk and i7 processor. Plenty horsepower.

After creating the application from scratch it completed one installation to Heroku without a problem. So I was over the moon with happiness after spending more than a week to try and resolve the issue.

After that I imported the sample entity model from the JDL studio - no changes to the design.

Now it hangs again....

Comment: Now rebuild a complete new Windows 7 laptop. Installed node v6.10.0, yarn v0.22.0, Java 1.8.0_121. Maven and create the default monolith application with PostgreSQL. No option on Cucumber, Gatling...

Maven builds fine with mvnw clean install

yarn install works fine...

mvnw package -X -Pprod -DskipTests runs and then hangs at 

PhantomJS is previously installed......

Don't know what to do anymore - can't get extra logging...

Comment: Finally given up on Yarn and completed the npm route.
Finally working!!
Seems Yarn is full of problems at the moment - especially in the Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

Using npm instead of Yarn resolved this problem. From all the tickets logged and questions posted it seems that Yarn is not stable at the moment on the Windows environment.
Works with npm.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you did to solve this issue

Comment: Hi Ivan - On Windows 10 I just could not get Yarn stable. All the forums I visited also complained about the same same issue. I thus removed Yarn in totality from my machine and used npm. This did not completely solve the problem as a lot of the newer tools uses yarn.
In the meantime I have now moved over to Mac. It is just such a more stable environment when do development. Docker works, yarn works, npm works, JHipster works. So using Yarn again.
Sorry I can't give you a clean "Do this to solve your problem"...

Comment: That's ok, what I thought was to migrate to linux for the sake of productivity and ease of use with docker, jhipster and other tools that simply run better and work together better with linux. I actually did just that with my work laptop, next step is to migrate my work desktop. Dual boot will do wonders for that. That makes sense, since I'll deploy my projects mainly to linux servers, and keeping dev and production environments the same will reduce problems in the long run.